# Fill canvas with images in javascript without having overlapping images

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

To fill a canvas with several images i am using the following code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script>
    function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        // get num of sources
        for ( var src in sources) {
            numImages++;
        }
        for ( var src in sources) {
            images[src] = new Image();
            images[src].onload = function() {
                if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                    callback(images);
                    }
            };
            images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    fitToContainer(canvas);
    var sources = {
        darthVader : 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
        yoda : 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
    };

    loadImages(sources, function(images) {
        context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 0,0);
        context.drawImage(images.yoda, 0, 0);
    });

    function fitToContainer(canvas) {
        canvas.style.width = '100%';
        canvas.style.height = '100%';
        canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
    }
    </script>
```

Although this is in fact filling the canvas with images, i am not able to position the images in order not to overlap them. I dont know ahead of time the sizes of pictures. Is there any library or framework than can easily do this for me or what direction can i go?

And the canvas has a limited size since it is inside a parent html element.

Comment: Please format your code better, remove those indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep track of the accumulated width of your images.

Then draw the next image to the right of that accumulated width

```
loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    var nextX=0;
    context.drawImage(images.darthVader, nextX,0);
    nextX+=images.darthVader.width;
    context.drawImage(images.yoda, nextX, 0);
    nextX+=images.yoda.width;
    // ...and so on...
});
```

Comment: My canvas has a limited size. It is limited by its parent html element. i added that to my question just now. With this i mean that i can't exceed the parent element size or the images wont be seen

Comment: The same concept applies! So also keep track of the maximum height you've used.  If your next image will exceed the canvas width then reset nextX to zero and start drawing below the previous maximum height.

Comment: If your images are allowed to be shuffled then you can use "bin packing" algorithms to fit the maximum rectangles inside your limited canvas area: http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/